# SQL Management Studio 2012 changing Visual Studio 2010 Styles

Tags: visual-studio-2010, styles, sql-server-2012

Anyone else run into this problem or know how to fix it?  I have Visual Studio 2010 installed on my computer and Sql Management Studio 2012.  Everytime I open management studio my styles for VS get changed so that I have to re-import them.  I tried importing the same styles into Management studio, but it still seems to change some of the styles back to default (I guess).  Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Actually - I don't even know if it has to do with SSMS.  It seems every time I restart VS I have to re-import my styles.  It doesn't reset them to default.  It just changes a few of them, but they're not what I set them to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had this problem for quite some time. It's not just because of SSMS, it seems that certain plug-ins/extensions compete for styles. When it happens, there is actually a much simpler solution than re-importing the styles.

Go to: Tools - Options - Fonts and Colors, then click 'OK'. That's it. You don't need to change anything, just simply hit OK when you are on the Fonts and Colors section of Options.

I discovered it by chance, but later confirmed it on forums that other people were using the same trick. It works for me every time, so far. Hope this helps.